# Mousing over to external display

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro, trackpad

When I have my external monitor hooked up, I access it by mousing off the left hand side of my Macbook display. Can I switch this so that I can access the external by mousing off to the right of My Macbook display?

The reason I ask, is my monitor is on the right side of my macbook, and it's unintuitive to mouse left to get to a screen on the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can drag the screens into the arrangement you wish in the Displays Control Panel, just click, hold, drag. The screen you are moving will show a red surround on both the panel & the display itself, so you know which is which.

The secondary display must, of course, be connected at this time. It will only appear in the panel when active.

[image]

Comment: OK thanks. I didn't see "arrangement" at the time because I had unplugged the display..