# Switching between two monitors stacked vertically

Tags: macos, display

So I have monitors stacked vertically.  Is there away to get my cursor to move between the monitors by going to the top of the lower monitor to get to the upper monitor?

Right now I have to go to the right of the primary to get to the other monitor.  I wonder if there's some third party app or system preference setting that I can set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to [Mousing over to external display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141401/mousing-over-to-external-display/141426#141426)

Works just as well for vertical as horizontal.